# Mac OSX: Error after installing Django - No module named django

Tags: python, django

I am using MacOS X 10.7.5 and am a TOTAL newb at Python

I am pretty sure django installed correctly as per https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Distributions

```
$ sudo port install py27-django
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-django
--->  Cleaning py27-django
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named django
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with that a prior Python was installed (2.7.1) previously and MacPorts installed a new one (2.7.6) but did not update the Mac Sym links etc

So I had to futz with my `PATH`

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
.
.
export PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH
.
.
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2013, 13:12:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print django.get_version()
1.5.1
```

Comment: I would suggest you use virtualenv (http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to isolate your project's dependencies and don't have to mess with system wide packages.